# Visual Studio 2013 The Interface is not supported

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, app-startup

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop installed on my machine. It installs fine with no errors until I try to start it. It then says

"The Operation Could not be completed, The interface is not supported"

I have tried looking this up and have not been able to find anything that has helped.

Things I tried

1. Uninstalling, Reinstalling and Rebooting
2. Completely removing .net451 and all of the associated packages I could find
3. Trying an Earlier version 2012 for Desk top and getting the same error.

Not sure what could be interfering.

I'm doing some Unity Development and MonoDevelop was getting the following error 
"CLR error: 80004005"

Which is a reference to conflicting .net packages

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Is there any more detailed error messages in Event Viewer?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Unlimited Pro 64bit. Yes there are several error messages in the Application log having to do with .Net, the thing thats puzzling me is I have uninstalled and reinstalled .Net completley and reinstalled it. Letting visual studio completley install its own thing. I then get the exact same error. I tried running a registry cleaner which indeed took care of many broken links but ultimately did not help.